# Determne if SQL Server database restored

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I need to check if a content database for SharePoint has been restored (as some point in the past).

Are there any log file entries - in SharePoint or SQL Server - I can check for to determine this? Or any other approach (apart from asking someone)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know when was the last time a database was restored, look into [`msdb.dbo.restorehistory`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187408.aspx).

If you want to know if a current restore operation is complete, check the database status in [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could try connecting to it. You won't be able to if its in the middle of a restore.